# Within radius - Slow query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT property.paon, property.saon, property.street, property.postcode, property.lastSalePrice, property.lastTransferDate,
 epc.ADDRESS1, epc.POSTCODE, epc.TOTAL_FLOOR_AREA,  
        (
            3959 * acos (
                cos (radians(54.6921))
                * cos(radians(property.latitude))
                * cos(radians(property.longitude) - radians(-1.2175))
                + sin(radians(54.6921))
                * sin(radians(property.latitude))
            )
        ) AS distance 
        FROM property 
        RIGHT JOIN epc ON property.postcode = epc.POSTCODE AND CONCAT(property.paon, ', ', property.street) = epc.ADDRESS1 
        WHERE property.paon IS NOT NULL AND epc.TOTAL_FLOOR_AREA > 0
        GROUP BY CONCAT(property.paon, ', ', property.street)

        HAVING distance < 1.4 
        ORDER BY property.lastTransferDate DESC
        LIMIT 10
```

table property has 22 million rows, table epc has 14 million rows

Without the GROUP BY and ORDER BY, it runs fast.

Property table often has the same property multiple times, but I need to select the one with the most current lastTransferDate.

If there is a better approach I'm open to it

Here is the explain of query:
[Explained Query Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtG5N.png)

Comment: In addition to the EXPLAIN, questions about query optimisation ALWAYS require SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables

Comment: `SELECT property.paon, property.saon, property.street, property.postcode, property.lastSalePrice, property.lastTransferDate,
 epc.ADDRESS1, epc.POSTCODE, epc.TOTAL_FLOOR_AREA,   ... GROUP BY CONCAT(property.paon, ', ', property.street) ` is bad SQL annyway.. read this https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/